# How can i collapse a column based on query id in R?

Tags: r

I have populated a list based on a condition usign this [R script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809876/how-to-populate-a-data-frame-based-on-condition-in-r/38810166#38810166) and i generated a summary table but unfortunately, i encountered a problem  with the table. Here it is

```
          id                              Alyr        Crub         Lala
TCONS_00002401.gene=XLOC_001343_TBH_1   Ortholog    Not found   Not found
TCONS_00002401.gene=XLOC_001343_TBH_1   Not found   Not found   Not found
TCONS_00002401.gene=XLOC_001343_TBH_1   Not found   Ortholog    Not found
```

As you can see, that there are three rows and 4 columns. What i was expected is to get a single idea for all three species (Alyr, Crub and Lala) but unfortunately there are three rows. How can i collapse these into one something like this?

```
               id                         Alyr        Crub        Lala
TCONS_00002401.gene=XLOC_001343_TBH_1   Ortholog    Ortholog    Not found
```

Comment: Firstly, replace `"Not found"` with `NA`. Also, where is the `"Ortholog"` in `Lala` coming from?

Comment: Your desired output isn't clear. Note how these two results "look" the same but are different structures `unlist(df[1,])` and `df[1,]`

Comment: Sorry.. i made a mistake in the desired output. I have corrected it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a way to filter out the non-mapped orthologues.

Meanwhile, a "quick-and-NotTooDirty" solution would be as follow:

dcast(subset(melt(df, id = "id"), value != "Not found"), id ~ variable + value)

where df is your input dataframe object.

You might have to rename the columns.

The first expression (i.e. melt(df, id = "id") creates a 3 column df.
The subset expression filters out records where value == "Not found".
Last, the dcast function puts it back as a wide dataframe, with only one row per id.

Dependency: reshape2 package (w.r.t. the melt and dcast functions)