# Replacing multiple cells (various row/column combinations) with one value in R data frame

Tags: r

Is there a way to condense the following code to list all the cells to the left of the <- on one line? I've tried commas, pipes and ampersands.

```
SchoolData[2,4]   <- Res.Stf0815[1,4]
SchoolData[3,5]   <- Res.Stf0815[1,4]
SchoolData[4,6]   <- Res.Stf0815[1,4]
SchoolData[5,7]   <- Res.Stf0815[1,4]

SchoolData[2,4], SchoolData[3,5], SchoolData[4,6], SchoolData[5,7] <- Res.Stf0815[1,4]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use matrix subsetting.

```
SchoolData[cbind(2:5, 4:7)] <- Res.Stf0815[1,4]
```

For more, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054259/r-relating-columns-to-row/33054345#33054345)